# Getting the compiler to auto-vectorize code in a sensible manner

Tags: c, optimization, fortran, vectorization, avx

I'm trying to figure out how to structure the main loop code for a numerical simulation in such a way that the compiler generates nicely vectorized instructions in a compact way.

The problem is most easily explained by a C pseudocode, but I also have a Fortran version which is affected by the same kind of issue. Consider the following loop where `lots_of_code_*` are some complicated **expressions** which produces a fair number of machine instructions.

```
void process(const double *in_arr, double *out_arr, int len)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        const double a = lots_of_code_a(i, in_arr);
        const double b = lots_of_code_b(i, in_arr);
        ...
        const double z = lots_of_code_z(i, in_arr);

        out_arr[i] = final_expr(a, b, ..., z);
    }
}
```

When compiled with an AVX target the Intel compiler generates code which goes like

```
process:
    AVX_loop
    AVX_code_a
    AVX_code_b
    ...
    AVX_code_z
    AVX_final_expr
    ...
    SSE_loop
    SSE_instructions
    ...
    scalar_loop
    scalar_instructions
    ...
```

The resulting binary is already quite sizable. My actual calculation loop, though, looks more like the following:

```
void process(const double *in_arr1, ... , const double *in_arr30, 
             double *out_arr1, ... double *out_arr30,
             int len) 
{
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        const double a1 = lots_of_code_a(i, in_arr1);
        ...
        const double a30 = lots_of_code_a(i, in_arr30);

        const double b1 = lots_of_code_b(i, in_arr1);
        ...
        const double b30 = lots_of_code_b(i, in_arr30);

        ...
        ...

        const double z1 = lots_of_code_z(i, in_arr1);
        ...
        const double z30 = lots_of_code_z(i, in_arr30);

        out_arr1[i] = final_expr1(a1, ..., z1);
        ...
        out_arr30[i] = final_expr30(a30, ..., z30);
    }
}
```

This results in a very large binary indeed (400KB for the Fortran version, 800KB for C99). If I now define `lots_of_code_*` as **functions**, then each function gets turned into non-vectorized code. Whenever the compiler decides to inline a function it does vectorize it, but seems to also duplicate the code each time as well.

In my mind, the ideal code should look like:

```
AVX_lots_of_code_a:
    AVX_code_a
AVX_lots_of_code_b:
    AVX_code_b
...
AVX_lots_of_code_z:
    AVX_code_z
SSE_lots_of_code_a:
    SSE_code_a
...
scalar_lots_of_code_a:
    scalar_code_a
...
...
process:
    AVX_loop
    call AVX_lots_of_code_a
    call AVX_lots_of_code_a
    ...
    SSE_loop
    call SSE_lots_of_code_a
    call SSE_lots_of_code_a
    ...
    scalar_loop
    call scalar_lots_of_code_a
    call scalar_lots_of_code_a
    ...
```

This clearly results in a much smaller code which is still just as well optimized as the fully-inlined version. With luck it might even fit in L1.

Obviously I can write the this myself using intrinsics or whatever, but is it possible to get the compiler to automatically vectorize in the way described above through "normal" source code?

I understand that the compiler will probably never generate separate symbols for each vectorized version of the functions, but I thought it could still just inline each function once inside `process` and use internal jumps to repeat the same code block, rather than duplicating code for each input array.

Comment: This question leads me to counter: why are processor intrinsics there?  AFAIK so the coder can do optimizations that the compiler is too dumb to do.

Comment: Well, the point is that the compiler generates decent code for each of the expressions. If I were to sit down and write _all_ of those expressions out in terms of intrinsics it would take forever and probably won't be as good as what the compiler does. The only dumb thing it's doing is repeating itself...

Comment: Understood, good point.

Comment: ...and not to mention that I would have to write the AVX, SSE and scalar version of each and all the expressions, separately. And then also have to write remainder loops for `process` myself. Really not feasible.

Comment: @St0fF The intrinsics are there for those who think they can do better than the compiler and are willing to invest in it. As of today, it's still very easy to beat the compiler in vectorization if you know what you're doing. But of course you still have to invest in it if you care.

Comment: I don't see how a compiler could possibly generate what you say is your ideal solution from the source you've provided. Your AVX versions pass in only 4 elements of the array, while the original functions pass in i and the entire array. The compiler would also have to detect that there are no side-effects?

Comment: @steabert I made a mistake in the assembly pseudocode, those AVX intermediate functions don't need to _take in_ four doubles, but they do _emit_ four doubles. Will fix this now. Good point about side effects checking though. I had wondered whether the functional language compilers can optimize this kind of code better than conventional ones. I can build in so much more information into the code through judicious use of types (the problem is from General Relativity so plenty of extra mathematical structures) but not sure if things like GHC are particularly optimized for HPC speed yet.

Comment: @Saran ok, but unless the functions are themselves vectorizable and are faster at producing four doubles simultaneously, I still don't see the need to vectorize this outer loop, if `lots_of_code_a` is the compute intensive part. If they are, then you can just combine them into one function and pass in the whole array once, like `lots_of_code_abcd...z(in_arr1,out_arr1)`. It all depends a lot on what those functions do, interdependency, etc.

Comment: I don't think you should look beyond C/C++ or Fortran. I only have HPC experience with the latter though, which has e.g. elemental procedures (maybe something similar exists for C). And if you are using these functions only here, you might think about inlining them manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Formal answer to questions like yours:

**Consider using OpenMP4.0 SIMD-enabled (I didn't say inlined) functions or equivalent proprietary mechanisms. Available in Intel Compiler or fresh GCC4.9.**

See more details here: https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/522650

Example:

```
//Invoke this function from vectorized loop
#pragma omp declare simd
    int vfun(int x, int y)
    {
        return x*x+y*y;
    }
```

It will give you capability to vectorize loop with function calls without inlining and as a result without huge code generation. (I didn't really explore your code snippet in details; instead I answered the question you asked in textual form)

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into this. A quick glance at the documentation suggests that it's primarily for pointwise scalar functions though, so the compiler might choke on things like differentiation routines (but then a lot of these aren't vectorizable without doing some memory gathers anyway..)

Comment: In fact the area of SIMD-enabled functions applicability is very wide. Take a look at SIMD-enabled function example, where the function has while loop inside: last 4 foils of http://extremecomputingtraining.anl.gov/files/2014/08/20140804-1030-1115-ATPESC-Argonne-Reinders.2.pdf. Or alternatively just explore a bit more about #pragma omp declare simd clauses, like "uniform", "linear", etc.

Comment: WRT your point of gathers/scatters - I'm not sure what is a relationship. YES: if you have essentially irregular stride and play with wide enough ISAs - then your performance will be much worse, no huge difference if you use compiler or intrinsics or assembly (in general case hand-coded horizontal sums will not make sense for AVX-512). In the other hands, it's NOT quite related to SIMD-enabled functions topic, and NO, presence of irregular stride will not prevent loops and functions from being somehow (more or less efficiently) vectorized by OpenMP4.0 compiler.

Answer (score 0):

The immediate problem that comes to mind is the lack of `restrict` on the input/output-pointers. The input is `const` though, so it's *probably* not too much of a problem, unless you have multiple output-pointers.
Other than that, I recommend `-fassociative-math` or whatever the ICC equivalent is. Structurally, you seem to iterate over the array, doing multiple independent operations on the array that are only munged together in the very end. Strict fp compliance might kill you on the array-operations.
Finally, there's probably no way this will get vectorized if you need more intermediate results than `vector_registers - input_arrays`.
Edit:
I think I see your problem now. You call the same function on different data, and want each result stored independently, right?
The problem is that the *same function* always writes to *the same output register*, so subsequent, vectorized calls would clobber earlier results. The solution could be:
A stack of results (either in memory or like the old x87 FPU-stack), that gets pushed every time. If in memory, it is slow, if x87, it's not vectorized. Bad idea.
Effectively multiple functions to write into different registers. Code duplication. Bad idea.
Rotating registers, like on the Itanium. You don't have an Itanium? You're not alone.
It's possible that this can't be easily vectorized on current architectures. Sorry.
Edit, you're apparently fine with going to memory:

```
void function1(double const *restrict inarr1, double const *restrict inarr2, \
               double *restrict outarr, size_t n)
{
  for (size_t i = 0; i<n; i++)
    {
      double intermediateres[NUMFUNCS];
      double * rescursor = intermediateres;
      *rescursor++ = mungefunc1(inarr1[i]);
      *rescursor++ = mungefunc1(inarr2[i]);
      *rescursor++ = mungefunc2(inarr1[i]);
      *rescursor++ = mungefunc2(inarr2[i]);
      ...
      outarr[i] = finalmunge(intermediateres[0],...,intermediateres[NUMFUNCS-1]);
    }    
}
```

This *might* be vectorizable. I don't think it'll be all that fast, going at memory speed, but you never know till you benchmark.

Comment: The actual code does use `restrict` but I left that off here for clarity. In any case that's not an issue for the Fortran version anyway. I'll look into `-fassociative-math`. I really don't require strict fp mode for the time being. Could you clarify you final point about intermediate results? Thanks!

Comment: Honestly, it's a bit difficult to tell where your problems are. A bit more context would be needed. There are lots of problems that can hit auto-vectorization. Function calls will prevent vectorization unless inlined, alignment can cause ridiculous code-bloat to the point where vectorization is no longer profitable... You get the point.

Comment: The problem here isn't so much that the code _isn't_ vectorized: the version without function calls looks to be well-vectorized by the compiler. The version _with_ function calls is, as you said, vectorized whenever calls are inlined. The point is that when I repeat the _same_ call multiple times, the compiler either inlines _each_ call separately (huge) or makes external calls to the non-vectorized code (slow). As far as context is concerned, the problem is a time-dependent PDEs system. Most, but not all, of those repeated calls are for finite-difference derivatives in various directions.

Comment: Regarding your edit: in our particular case we require so many intermediate values that things will neeed to be pushed onto the stack anyway, vectorized or not. (Things should still fit in L3 in the worst case) So the point about the register needing to be clobbered is not something which can be avoided at all. Everything else being equal, then, using vector adds and vector multiplies should still be somewhat faster than scalar adds and scalar multiplies.

Comment: If you're going to use `-fassociative-math` you might as well use `-Ofast` instead.

Comment: I think the ICC equivalent to `-fassociative-math` is `-fp-model fast=n` but can't be entirely sure. The man page doesn't say anything specific about associativity assumptions these fp modes, only that it's nonstandard and may be faster.

Answer (score 0):

If you moved the lots_of_code blocks into separate compilation units without the for loop, they will probably not vecorize. Unless the compiler has a motive for vectorization, it will not vectorize the code because vectorization might lead for longer latencies in the pipelines. To get around that, split the loop into 30 loops, and put each one of them in a separate compilation unit like that:

```
for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
{
    lots_of_code_a(i, in_arr1);
}
```